# Guest Ethernet Network?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, vlan

I work in Security Systems, so I'm usually testing alot of different new products, such as cameras, alarm control panels, and other ip-connected devices.

I'm looking for a way to create an isolated network, where these devices can access the internet and have their own LAN, without having acces to my LAN (personal TVs, computer workstations).

I did this for my ecobee thermostats by simply enabling the guest wifi network on my router, and checking the box to only allow deviced on that SSID to have internet access, and not LAN access. I'm imagining that some VLAN work might be involved?

I have an intermediate understanding of networks, so feel free to fire away with questions and/or solutions. I'm also providing a very simple diagram of my current network below!

Fiber from the Street-->into small housing so that an LC-connector patch cable can go from there into an SFP module straight into our router (ATT BGW-3200)

ROUTER PORTS 1-4 (1-ALARM PANEL, 2-VONAGE MODEM, 3-NOT USED, 4-CAT6 PATCH CABLE TO 8 PORT TP-LINK 1 GIG SWITCH)

Comment: Get a good quality managed Switch and set up an isolated VLAN for this. Setup will depend on the Switch you select.

Comment: any recommendations for some good managed switches?

do you think the tp-link brand of manages switches is too cheap?

Comment: Cisco has good managed switches and support. If you wish to us TP Link look at the documentation carefully. Cisco managed switches are reasonably priced.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off topic.